# What is the difference between Some and Option in Rust?

Tags: types, rust, option-type

Are they the same? I can sometimes see the documentation use them as if they were equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Option` type is defined as:

```
enum Option<T> {
    None,
    Some(T),
}
```

Which means that the `Option` type can have either a `None` or a `Some` value.

See also:

- [What are Some and None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24771655/155423)
- [Why don't Option's Some and None variants need to be qualified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546644/155423)

Comment: Does this mean some documentation of Rust is plain wrong? Example: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.10/std/io/struct.IncomingConnections.html - That one says the next method always returns Some, while really it returns an Option.

Comment: To add to this; the point of Option types are to represent nullable (None) values without including the notion of the null pointer in the language. Using an enum means you MUST `match {}` it and since `match` expressions must be exhaustive, you then must handle the `None` branch explicitly.

Comment: @JeroenBollen - It's not wrong to say it returns an `Option` if it always returns `Some` since `Some` is an `Option`.

Comment: @JeroenBollen Its return value is always a value of type `Option<...>`. But this type overly broad (it's mandated by the iterator trait), and hence the part you refer to informs the reader: The return value is always a value `Some(blah)` for some `blah`, never `None`. It's like saying "this function always returns 0". 0 is not a type, it's a value, but the statement still makes sense.

Comment: @Jeroen Bollen: it's not incorrect to say that a method always returns a certain value.

Answer (score 11):

No, they are not the same, and documentation treating them as if they were the same is either wrong, or a misunderstanding on your side. `Option` is a type (more accurately, a *generic type constructor*; `Option<i32>` is a type, and so is `Option<String>`). `Some` is a *constructor*. Aside from acting as a function `fn Some<T>(T x) -> Option<T>`, it's also used in pattern matching:

```rust
let mut opt: Option<i32>; // type
opt = Some(1); // constructor
opt = None; // other constructor
match opt {
    Some(x) => {
        // pattern
        println!("Got {}", x);
    }
    None => {
        // other pattern
        println!("Got nothing");
    }
}
```