# What are Some and None?

Tags: rust, option-type

I came across some output I don't understand using `Vec::get`. Here's the code:

```
fn main() {
    let command = [('G', 'H'), ('H', '5')];

    for i in 0..3 {
        print!(" {} ", i);
        println!("{:?}", command.get(i));
    }
}
```

the output is

```
 0 Some(('G', 'H'))
 1 Some(('H', '5'))
 2 None
```

I've dabbled in Haskell before, and by that I mean looked at a tutorial site for 10 minutes and ran back to C++, but I remember reading something about `Some` and `None` for Haskell. I was surprised to see this here in Rust. Could someone explain why `.get()` returns `Some` or `None`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The signature of `get` (for slices, *not* `Vec`, since you're using an array/slice) is

```rust
fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T>
```

That is, it returns an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), which is an enum defined like

```rust
pub enum Option<T> {
    None,
    Some(T),
}
```

`None` and `Some` are the *variants* of the enum, that is, a value with type `Option<T>` can either be a `None`, or it can be a `Some` containing a value of type `T`. You can create the `Option` enum using the variants as well:

```rust
let foo = Some(42);
let bar = None;
```

This is the same as the core `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a` type in Haskell; both represent an optional value, it's either there (`Some`/`Just`), or it's not (`None`/`Nothing`).

These types are often used to represent failure when there's only one possibility for why something failed, for example, `.get` uses `Option` to give type-safe bounds-checked array access: it returns `None` (i.e. no data) when the index is out of bounds, otherwise it returns a `Some` containing the requested pointer.

See also:

- [Why don't Option's Some and None variants need to be qualified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546644/155423)
- [What is the difference between Some and Option in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24022859/155423)

Answer (score 12):

Think of `Some` and `None` as the canonical "safe" way of working around the fact that the Rust language does not support "safe" use of `NULL` pointers.  Since the length of your `Vec` is 3, and you have only specified two pairs, the third pair is effectively `NULL`; instead of returning `NULL`, it returns `None`.

Rust provides safety guarantees by forcing us at compile-time, via `Some` / `None`, to always deal with the possibility of `None` being returned.

Comment: *the Rust language does not support (unsafe) NULL pointers* — that's [not completely true](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.null.html), but the spirit of your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks; I can see that they would be necessary for interfacing with C.

Comment: Not just that, but also for the times when you need unsafe. Data structures will often use raw pointers internally.

Comment: Another good point.  I've edited my answer to make it more accurate.

Comment: To go back to the world of Haskell, would "Some | None" in Rust be a monad like it is in Haskell?

Answer (score 8):

`command` is not a vector (type `Vec<T>`), it is a fixed-size array (type `[(char, char); 2]` in your case), and arrays are automatically borrowed into slices (views into arrays), hence you can use all methods defined on slices, including [`get`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get):

> Returns the element of a slice at the given index, or `None` if the index is out of bounds.

The behavior is pretty obvious: when given index is valid, it returns `Some` with the element under that index, otherwise it returns `None`.

There is another way to access elements in a slice - the indexing operator, which should be familiar to you:

```
let nums = [1, 2, 3];
let x = nums[1];
```

It returns the element of the slice directly, but it will fail the current task if the index is out of bounds:

```
fn main() {
    let x = [1, 2];
    for i in 0..3 {
        println!("{}", x[i]);
    }
}
```

This program fails:

```
% ./main2
1
2
task '<main>' failed at 'index out of bounds: the len is 2 but the index is 2', main2.rs:4
```

The `get()` method is needed for convenience; it saves you from checking in advance if the given index is valid.

If you don't know what `Some` and `None` really are and why they are needed in general, you should read the [official](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/error-handling.html#the-option-type) [tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/generics.html), it explains it because it is very basic concept.

Answer (score 6):

Option enum has 2 variants.

1- `None` is used to indicate failure or no value

2- `Some` which is tuple-struct that wraps the value

If you need to write this structure in OOB, for example in `typescript`, you would write like this. This would make it easier to visualize the situation

- Define Option interface as derived class

  ```
  interface Option<T = any> {
    // pass all the methods here 
    // unwrap is used to access the wrapped value
    unwrap(): T;
  }
  ```
- write `Some` class which inherits from `Option`

`Some` class returns a value

```
class Some<T> implements Option<T> {
  private value: T;
 
  constructor(v: T) {
    this.value = v;
  }
 
  unwrap(): T {
    return this.value
}}
```

- Write `None` class which also inherits from `Option`

`None` class returns null

```
class None<T> implements Option<T> {
 // you do not need constructor here     
  unwrap(): T {
    return null as T;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a really interesting example, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers discussing the return type for get() being [option enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) are accurate, but I think what is helpful is how to remove the some from the prints. To do that a quick way is to just call the unwrap on the option, although this is not production recommended. For a discussion on option take a look at the rust book [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html?highlight=option#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values).

[Updated with unwrap code in playground (below)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2398c6a14e69448ed78b35e8f4949573)

```
fn main() {
    let command = [('G', 'H'), ('H', '5')];

    for i in 0..3 {
        print!(" {} ", i);
        println!("{:?}", command.get(i).unwrap());
    }
}
```