# How to represent missing or invalid values?

Tags: types, rust

Since Rust does not have `None`/`null`/`nil` values, how can I represent missing or invalid values in an array?

Comment: [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/index.html) for possible missing values or [`Result<T, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/index.html) for possible invalid values.

Comment: @ljedrz Could you show me in context of `let color = [255, 0, 255]` ? For example how to make `color[1]` = `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all [discussed in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values). Please ensure you read through that book; much time has been spent addressing many questions and concerns that newcomers have.

> Since Rust does not have `None`

I'm not sure why you say that, considering that [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) (and by extension [`Option::None`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#variant.None)) is a *key* piece of Rust. In fact, it's so important that it's imported [in the prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/v1/).

If you'd like an array with one "missing" value:

```
let color = [Some(255), None, Some(255)];
```

In many languages with the concept of nil / null, every value can be the type you expect it to be **or** the special type nil / null. This isn't true in Rust — a `Foo` and an `Option<Foo>` are distinct types and you can't "forget" to handle the missing value:

```
let sum = color[0] + color[1];
```

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `std::option::Option<{integer}>`
 --> src/main.rs:4:15
  |
4 |     let sum = color[0] + color[1];
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `std::option::Option<{integer}>`
```

You have to use *pattern matching* or the helper methods on `Option` (which do pattern matching internally) to "unpack" the values and distinctly handle the `Some` and `None` cases.

See also:

- [Some and None, what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24771655/155423)

Comment: Thank you! I wish that I could upvote your answer multiple times! "a `Foo` and an `Option<Foo>` are distinct types" this really cleared it up for me (including the example of `color[0] + color[1]`). I am (slowly) reading the book and it's great and I am also listening and reading other sources too.