# Why don't Option's Some and None variants need to be qualified?

Tags: rust

According to the [docs for `Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), `Option` is an enum with variants `Some<T>` and `None`.

Why is it possible to refer to `Some` and `None` without qualifying them?

For example, this works fine:

```
let x = Option::Some(5);
match x {
    Some(a) => println!("Got {}", a),
    None => println!("Got None"),
}
```

But this fails to compile:

```
enum Foo<T> {
    Bar(T),
    Baz,
}
let x = Foo::Bar(5);
match x {
    Bar(a) => println!("Got {}", a),
    Baz => println!("Got Baz"),
}
```

The error from the compiler is `` unresolved enum variant, struct or const `Bar` ``

Comment: Here’s a (later) dupe target with a [more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71267790/438273)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Rust prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html), which is automatically inserted into every source file, contains this line:

```
pub use option::Option::{self, Some, None};
```

Which brings `Option` and both its variants in scope.