# Why can we use `Some(value)` instead of `Option::Some(value)` in Rust?

Tags: rust

Shouldn't the variant of an enum be fully qualified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variant of an `enum` can be imported into the current namespace too.

```
enum Test {
    A,
    B,
}

use Test::{A,B};

fn main() {
    let t = A;
    match t {
        A => println!("A"),
        B => println!("B"),
    };
}
```

And it turns out that the prelude of Rust, on top of importing `Option`, also imports `Some` and `None`.

Comment: Could you explain the `prelude` a little more? I think it's useful in this context and I really like the question :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Well, just as I was looking for an existing question explaining the prelude that I could link to I found a clear duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546644/why-dont-options-some-and-none-variants-need-to-be-qualified/30546727#30546727 ...

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Actually, I could not find a single explanation of what the prelude was and what its role was on SO, so I gave it a shot in a dedicated question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36384840/147192). I would appreciate your review, if you have the time.

Comment: Oops, perfect duplicate, indeed :P Thanks for opening a new question, I upvoted an commented.