# What is the prelude?

Tags: rust

When talking about imports, the word *prelude* is used every so often by the rustaceans.

What is this *prelude* they talk about?

How does it affect my Rust programs?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In Rust, in order to use a symbol, you must either:

- have defined the symbol in the current scope
- have imported the symbol in the current scope via a `use` directive: `use std::mem;`
- be referring to the symbol using its absolute path: `std::mem::replace`

however, some very few symbols can be used without such actions: `Option` or `Copy` for example!

This is due to the [Rust prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/).

A number of traits, types and functions were judged to be so frequently used that it made sense not to require that their use required explicitly importing the necessary symbols each and every time. This is achieved thanks to two implicit actions taken by the compiler:

- at the root of every crate, the compiler injects an implicit `extern crate std;`
- in every module, the compiler injects an implicit `use std::prelude::v1::*;` (for now)

`std::prelude::v1` is just a regular module which re-exports those frequently used symbols using the `pub use ...` syntax. Its exact content can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/v1/).

---

A number of other libraries, or even sub-components of the standard library also define a `prelude` module that you may import with the same glob import syntax: `use xxx::prelude::*;`. Unlike the `std::prelude` however those are not special-cased by the compiler and therefore require explicit importing.

---

The compiler is agnostic to the exact content of the prelude, therefore if one was to replace the `std` crate with their own (for example, in embedded development) then one would decide what goes into their `std::prelude::v1` module.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Ah good point, I had started writing the answer with `vec!`, `panic!`, ... but could not find where those came from. I'll remove it.

Comment: [This RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/890) proposes to add prelude functionality to user crates. It has been closed some time ago, but might be revived in the future.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for the clear explanation. It seems like that `println!` macro does not come from `std::prelude`?

Comment: @JeremyKao: It does, if you go to the [prelude page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/) it's listed in the macros section. (Just CTRL+F `println`)

Comment: Thanks! I was using `use anchor_lang::prelude::*` for ages and wondering where the name came from.