# Using a module from the standard library works in my crate root, but not in a module

Tags: module, rust, constants

I can reference `std::f64::NEG_INFINITY` in my `main.rs` and there is no problem. However, if another module references the same constant, the compiler complains: `Use of undeclared type or module 'std::f64'`.

Here is my `main.rs`:

```
mod bar;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::f64::NEG_INFINITY);
}
```

Here is my `bar.rs`:

```
fn foo() {
    println!("{}", std::f64::NEG_INFINITY);
}
```

`main.rs` and `bar.rs` are in the same folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for separate files; here's a reproduction:

```
fn main() {}

mod bar {
    fn foo() {
        println!("{}", std::f64::NEG_INFINITY);
    }
}
```

At the root of your crate, the `std` crate has been automatically imported as part of [the prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36384840/155423). That inserts the *path* `std` starting from the root.

Once you start writing code in a module, however, you are no longer at the root, and when you try to make use of an item, paths are relative by default. Thus, inside of `mod bar`, the path `std::f64::NEG_INFINITY` would be the absolute path `::bar::std::f64::NEG_INFINITY`, which doesn't exist.

You can solve this in two main ways:

1. Bring the path into scope by using the `use std;` statement. Note that *this* statement uses absolute paths by default, so *this* `std` is `::std`.
2. Provide an absolute path at each usage: `println!("{}", ::std::f64::NEG_INFINITY)`.