# std::result vs core::result::Result

Tags: rust

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/, the stuct Result is defined at `std::result`, however:

```
fn test() -> std::Result<u32, u32> {
    Ok(0)
}
```

wont compile. I have to change to `core::result::Result<u32, u32>`

How could I know, by Rust's page for `std::result`, how to import it?

Comment: Result is defined in `std::result::Result` std::result is the module path

Comment: You don't have to import it; it's [part of the prelude](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36384840/155423). Just type `Result`.

Comment: @Stargateur whats the difference between `core::result::Result` and `std::result::Result`?

Comment: there are the same structure, std just reexport it. Like duplicate said, a lot of thing in core are just reexported in std.