# Rust - Include rust module in another directory

Tags: rust

This is my directory structure

```
src/
├── lib.rs
├── pages/
│   ├── mod.rs
│   ├── home_page.rs
└── components/
    ├── mod.rs
    └── header.rs
```

Inside my `pages/home_page.rs` I try to access my `pub struct Header` which is inside `components/header.rs`.

My `components/mod.rs` looks like this: `pub mod header;` which works fine because inside `lib.rs` - I can use it like:

```
mod components;
use components::header::Header;
```

However, I don't know how to access it in `pages/homepage.rs`. How can get access to that struct? Is it something in Cargo.toml?

Comment: If you follow this guys talks on Youtube.. Videos 1 and 2 show a refactoring to break a project down into such a structure. Maybe it'll help you. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtbwxVtHxPeIYJtu1g53FgLPGN9WYgG2l

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a whole bunch of Rust keywords to navigate between the modules of your crate:

```
super::components::Header
// `super` is like a `parent` of your current mod
```

```
crate::components::Header
// `crate` is like a root of you current crate
```

And to include submodules of current mod:

```
self::submodule1::MyStruct
// `self` is like current module
```

You can read more about that [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html)

Also it is good idea to make a `prelude` mod of your crate and include all main items of your crate there, so then you can include them just by passing `use crate::prelude::*`.
You can read more about `prelude` [in offical rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384840/what-is-the-prelude).

Answer (score 1):

Inside my `src/pages/home_page.rs` I can use my header like: `use crate::components::header::Header;`