# Why is a "use" needed for env::args() but not Vec::new()?

Tags: rust

For `env::args()` I am having to explicitly include the env module by

```rust
use std::env;
```

But I am able to use `Vec::new()` without the `use std::vec` statement, though both are from the standard library.

Is there a subset of standard library modules that are made available by default for all programs?

Comment: See also: [What is the prelude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384840/what-is-the-prelude)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, everything in the [Rust prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/index.html) (including `std::vec::Vec`) is available by default.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all programs implicitly import all members of the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html) module.