# How are "Some" and "None" from "Option" accessible at any scope?

Tags: rust

Is there some compiler built-in functionality going on, or would it be possible to implement your own enum with its variants globally accessible with rust code alone? If yes, how?

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My Question was about `Some` and `None`, not `Option`. For example:

```
enum MyOption<T> {
    MySome(T),
    MyNone,
}

impl<T> MyOption<T> {
    fn is_some(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Self::MySome(_) => true,
            Self::MyNone => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Even from "inside", I have to tell the compiler to find them in `Self`. So is there a way to do it like `Option` and have my `MySome` and `MyNone` linked to `MyOption` from anywhere I write them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust has a module called the "prelude", accessible at `std::prelude`, and all of its members are imported into every module by default.

If you define your own names that shadow names in the prelude, your names take precedence. This is common for types like `Result`, in the following pattern:

```rust
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, MyCustomError>;
```

Whenever this is in scope, it takes precedence over the `Result` type included from the prelude.

Note that some things in the prelude are treated in special ways by the compiler (for example `Box` has built-in functionality) but you can still override the name.

You can import enum variants like regular items. For example, you can write:

```rust
use MyOption::*;

fn handle_my_option(o: MyOption) {
  match o {
    MyOk(foo) => {},
    MyNone => {},
  }
}
```

However, you can't have these automatically imported like the ones in the prelude (you can't add anything the prelude essentially).

If you have lots of these types, you can bundle them into a file and glob import them:

```rust
// src/my_prelude.rs
pub use crate::my_option::MyOption;  // reexport the enum itself
pub use crate::my_option::MyOption::*;  // reexport the individual variants
// any other things you want everywhere

// src/foo.rs
use crate::my_prelude::*;

fn foo() -> MyOption<()> {
  if bar() {
    MySome(()),
  } else {
    MyNone
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @rak See the documentation of the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/index.html) module. Further down it says: "std::option::Option::{self, Some, None}, a type which expresses the presence or absence of a value. This type is so commonly used, its variants are also exported."

Comment: @cameron1024: Yes thank you that was what I was looking for with my question. I knew about preludes just didn't know I could `use` variants of an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Rust has a [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html) module which is implicitly included in every file.

This module reexports commonly used things such as `Option` and its variants, but also types such as `String`, traits such as `Clone`, and functions such as `drop`.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question.